How do I bypass frp on att vista phone
I just purchased a AT&T vista phone model number WTATTRW2 from a friend who forgot the email account.I have tried every trick on YouTube but can't bypass the frp.I can reach the settings but the apps won't respond. I can download apk's to it but when I try to install them, the package installer stops. I would really appreciate any suggestions anyone can offer.
Thank you
